# What is the meaning of "You're rolling one for two." if the context is about someone who is running late to go somewhere

Tags: idioms

I don't really understand about it. Especially because there is "one for two" after "rolling".

English isn’t my first language, so please excuse any mistakes and I'm sorry if the question is off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for your question.  Can you provide more context to where you saw or heard the phrase?  I (personally) have not heard this phrase used in any context before now.

Comment: It could mean any number of things: rolling dice, rolling a joint of marijuana, mugging a pair of people, and so on. You have to provide more context. (I have never heard of *rolling* apply to being late.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a statistic of past behavior. The speaker says that you have shown him/her that you're late 1 out of 2 times, effectively half of the time. The use of dice is just a linguistic flourish; I've also heard a similar idiom for baseball hitting percentages (you're batting 1000 today!).